# Insert into table when record does not exist

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

When inserting a VAT number for a customer, it checks if the value I enter exists in the `TaxVATNumTable`.

This check is active in the method: `checkVATNum` in the table `TaxVATNumTable`:

```
if (!TaxVATNumTable::existOptionalCountryRegion(vatNum))
ret = checkFailed(strFmt("@SYS83770", vatNum, fieldId2pname(common.TableId, fieldId), countryRegion, tableId2pname(tableNum(TaxVATNumTable))));
```

I want to comment out the: `ret = ...` line and build in a code that the VAT number I enter at the customer is being inserted in the `TaxVATNumTable`.

This table does not have an `insert` method, what is the best way to approach this situation? Create an `insert` method for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `checkVATNum()` method should not be modified as you always want to confirm that value exists.

What you should do is identify where the inserting action is happening, and perform a check and insert before the `checkVATNum()` logic.

If a table doesn't have an `insert()` method, you just right click on the table methods and click `Override Method > Insert`. If you do this though, `insert_recordset` operations will not be efficient against the specific table as the `insert()` logic will need to be called, and it will break down to a regular style operation.